# Reference for the "Quotient Variance"?

Tags: probability, reference-request

I have recently encountered the expression

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}$$

in my research. This can be thought of as an analogue of the variance $\mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ where one divides instead of subtracting.
Does this quantity have some well-known name? I recall seeing it before in some probabilist's work, but tracking down a particular reference would take quite some time.

Comment: I think its reciprocal appears in some places like [Paley–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality), but I am not sure if this quantity has ever been given a wildly accepted name.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this object itself has a special name, but it can be expressed in terms of the [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) (CV):

$${E[X^2] \over E[X]^2}=1+\left({\sigma \over\mu}\right)^2=1+CV^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

I found the probabilist's reference that I mentioned in the post (thankfully it did not take too long).
My quantity is closely related to equation 2.1 of [Variance Estimates and Almost Euclidean Structure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10244.pdf), where the quantity

$$\beta(X) = \frac{\mathsf{Var}(X)}{\mathbb{E}[X]^2} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}-1$$
is defined (though not named).
This quantity can be used to relate the median and mean of $X$, specifically one can show that

$$\left|\frac{\mathsf{med}(X)}{\mathbb{E}[X]} - 1\right| \leq \sqrt{\beta(X)}.$$

It also appears it can be useful for other things (various results in the study of log-concave random variables in particular).